# Windows 8.1 BSOD CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED after waking up from sleep

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, sleep, minidumps

Windows 8.1 (u1) is unable to wake up correctly from sleep : it wakes up, shows the screen, and then dies with a BSOD.

So I disabled automatic restart after BSOD, and then was able to identify it : CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED. Further it said that it was trying to do a memory dump, but never went beyond 0%. True to it, I was not able to find the dump in the minidumps folder.

Windows 7 on another HDD sleeps and wakes up perfectly fine.

Hardware :

- MSI P45 Platinum
- ST3360320AS 360GB HDD connected through eSATA in external case
- ST31000524AS 1TB HDD internal SATA (AHCI)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Originally I ignored the problem and took care not to let it sleep.

While I was routinely checking device manager however, I was surprised that the **Storage Controllers** did not even have the second SATA controller present on my board, the JMB363. I originally thought drivers were not required, but this indicated otherwise.

I installed the latest drivers (R1.17.65) and then, for good measure also checked for the Intel AHCI controller. Irritatingly I found the entry in IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers **along with**

- ATA Channel 0
- ATA Channel 1
- Standard PCI IDE Dual Channel Controller

Having taken care to use only AHCI from the beginning, I disliked any presence of IDE/ATA, so installed the Intel AHCI drivers (Intel RST).

That fixed the issue. I don't know if only the JMB36x driver would have been enough, can't check now.

Comment: Tnx 4 sharing solution. Helped 4 me as well (=